# How to set a mime type for generated chunks by Angular CLI?

Tags: angular

In my Angular app I use lazy loading for serving a module on a specific route. When I build my app it generates chunks in the dist folder.

When I'm trying to load my app in a browser it throws the error:
"Refused to execute script from '0.chunk.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Is there anyway I can either add the MIME type when the file is being generated or disable the MIME type checking?

I have a basic routing file containing:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'app',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: ‘new’,
        loadChildren: 'app/base/new/new.module#NewModule'
    }
 ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

I build my app using the following command in the package.json:

```
"build": "rm -rf dist && ng build --prod --output-hashing none --build-optimizer",
```

In the dist folder it generates:

```
chunk {0} 0.chunk.js () 2.54 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} 1.chunk.js () 262 kB  [rendered]
chunk {2} main.bundle.js (main) 942 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 94.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.bundle.css (styles) 50.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {5} inline.bundle.js (inline) 1.36 kB [entry] [rendered]
```

Comment: would you please show us your code so far, otherwise it is difficult for people to provide constructive help.

Comment: Updated my message with code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did not found a way to set the mime type for chunks but I did found out that removing lazy loading also ensures no chunks are created and therefor solves my problem.

Followed this guide to remove lazy loading:
https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-module-loading-eager-lazy-and-preloading

Answer (score 0):

While I got the same error in Firefox, Chrome gave me some more insight, showing me 404s for all my bundles when opening a route that points to a lazy loaded module. I figured that changing the base href in my `index.html` fixed the issue.

I changed `<base href=".">` to `<base href="/">` and things started to work.